# How to compare and store the compared elements form 1D and 2D arrays c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am confused in comparing arrays
my code is:

result is a 1D array and symboltable1 is a 2D array... these arrays contain at least 100, 100 values

```
for (int row = 0; row < symboltable1.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < symboltable1.GetLength(1); column++)
    {
        for (int we = 0; we < result.Length; we++)
          if (result[we].Contains(symboltable1[row, column]))
            listBox1.Items.Add("vliad");
          else
            listBox2.Items.Add("invalid");          
    }
}
```

what I want now is how to store valid terms in another 2D array named symboltable2?
by valid terms, i mean the terms which are in both of the above said arrays????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the generic function below to flatten a 2D array into an `IEnumerable`, put elements into a hash set, and check the terms against that hash table.

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(T[,] data) {
    var r = data.GetLength(0);
    var c = data.GetLength(1);
    return Enumerable.Range(0, r*c).Select(i => data[i/c, i%c]);
}

var symTableItems = new HashSet<string>(Flatten(symboltable1));
var allValid = result.Where(s => symTableItems.Contains(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: i have a code containg thousands of interlinked lines i can change a bit of it now..... wot i asked was, how to store the valid values?

Comment: @MomoPomo Once you have your symTableItems flattened, getting all valid values becomes a straightforward LINQ query. Take a look at the edit.

Comment: so this, "allvalid" is containg the values? how do i show thm on the form now? using a listbox? it isnt working

Comment: @MomoPomo Can you put a breakpoint in the debugger and see what you get in the `allValid` list?

Comment: @MomoPomo Before you can show them, you need to get them. Can you confirm that you are getting them in your program?